# Event Study - how to control for confounding events?

Tags: event-study

Say that I am attempting to estimate the cumulative abnormal returns CAR for a firm due to an event $X$. My event window is taken to be 1 week long (day 0 to 6).

However, on day 2, another big event $Y$ occurs.

How do I estimate the CAR due to $X$, controlling for the fact that $Y$ happened?

For parsimony, let's assume that I am using the market model to generate normal returns.

Comment: There is probably no way you will be able to disentangle the effects of $X$ and $Y$, unless you have some (similar) firms that get affected by $X$ and not $Y$ or vice-versa.

Comment: In event studies on share repurchases it is common use to elude firms from the sample having an additional event **in the event day 0**. If further events prior or after the event day occur, these firms stay within the sample and the co-event is **ignored**. However, you may check your result for both exclusion and considering the firm with additional events and report it as robustness test. In the end, it is up to you and depends on the ratio of firms with additional events within the full sample as exclusion may shrink your sample to few firms, which leads to worse statistical properties.